# Laravel change database data in filter.php

Tags: php, database, laravel

I want to change database data before and after App function in filter.php file.
I try to do like in that tutorial:
http://alex.leonard.ie/2013/08/02/laravel-tracking-last-activity-date-of-authorised-user/

```
App::before(function($request)
{
   $user = Auth::user();
   $user->online = 1;
   $user->save();
});
```

But i get error: ErrorException (E_UNKNOWN) Creating default object from empty value

Mybe someone can help?

Comment: But, if the user isn't logged in? Will throw some error to You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
App::before(function($request)
{
    if (Auth::check()){
      $user = Auth::user();
      $user->online = 1;
      $user->save();
    }
});
```

Note that this will only work if the user is logged in.

Comment: Try change, but still get: Creating default object from empty value

Comment: Do you have a user logged in?

Comment: Edited my answer to check for user login.

Comment: Thanks before function now work I forget add if (Auth::user()). I now want to use App::after to change online = 0, but after do in every link, what to change data if only session end?

Comment: You can only do this on a manual logout, or by setting a timeout on the session and setting the $user->online field to 0 at timeout.

Answer (score -2):

Try this.

`App::before(function($request){
    if(Auth::check()){ 
    $user = Auth::user();
    $user->online = 1;
    $user->save();
    }
    });`